# How to remove bxslider image border

Tags: css, bxslider

I have problem with remove border around image in bxslider. I checked other solutions from stack overflow but they didnt help me.
Please help me with this case.

For ex this didn't help me:

```
.bx-wrapper {
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}
```

my css:

```
.bx-viewport, .bx-wrapper{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.bx-wrapper .bx-viewport {
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: none !important;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

}
.bxslider{
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
ul.bxslider {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

my html code:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
   <li><img src="img/bx-slider/img1.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="img/bx-slider/img2.jpg" /></li>
   <li><img src="img/bx-slider/img3.jpg" /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
.bx-wrapper img{
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border: 0;
}
```